# How to purchase more licences for a Microsoft Subscription via the API

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to automatically add a Power BI Pro Licence to Office account in the domain that i manage and i am getting stuck when i Don't have enough Licences to assign another

I can do the 'Assigning' part using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/assignLicense which works until there aren't any spare licences, where it returns: "Subscription with SKU {id} does not have any available licenses."

To make this a fully automated process, i need to:

1. Automatically purchase a new Power BI Licence.
2. Assign that Licence to a user.

I cannot identity an API endpoint which allows me to do step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph, nor any other Microsoft API, supports purchasing O365 licenses. That is done through their Microsoft rep (if they have one) or through the [Admin Portal](https://portal.office.com) directly.

Comment: Yes it can currently be done manually through the Admin Portal but i was wanting to see if there was an automatic process for this. Thanks though